# Field renormalization of scalar Yang-Mills

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, yang-mills

In most books, one can find the field renormalization $Z_3$ in Yang-Mills with fermionic matter in the fundamental. In the $\overline{MS}$ scheme, tt is given by
$$
Z_3 = 1 + \frac{g^2}{16\pi^2 \epsilon} \left[ \frac{10}{3} T_A  - \frac{8}{3} n_F T_F \right] + {\cal O}(g^3)
$$
One often writes $\delta_3 = Z_3 - 1$.

This formula can be found in

1. Eq. (73.33) of Srednicki.
2. Eq. (26.83) of Matt Schwartz' book.
3. Eq. (16.74) of P&S
   etc.

However, I can't find any reference that lists how this result is modified if there's scalar matter present. I've already computed it and I get
$$
Z_3 = 1 + \frac{g^2}{16\pi^2 \epsilon} \left[ \frac{10}{3} T_A  - \frac{8}{3} n_F T_F - \frac{2}{3} n_S T_F \right] + {\cal O}(g^3)
$$
Is this correct?

In particular, I'm really interested in computing ALL the counterterms of Yang-Mills in the presence of scalar matter. Is there any reference out there that already does that so I can match my results?

Comment: Also to partially answer your question. Any book with a section on GUTs should provide the correct formula, though I've never seen a reference actually derive it in full.